# NGinx redirect rule

Tags: nginx, 301-redirect

i need to redirect specific paths on nginx but cannot find the way :)
In particular redirect 301 this urls

```
http://www.domain.com/c/Integratori-di-Proteine/Universal-.html
http://www.domain.com/c/Integratori-Aminoacidi/+Watt.html
```

to respective

```
http://www.domain.com/c/Integratori-di-Proteine/
http://www.domain.com/c/Integratori-Aminoacidi/
```

I tried without success this

```
location ~ ^/c/(.+)/(.+)\.html { rewrite ^ http://www.domain.com/$1/; }
```

thanks

Comment: Your question is missing the log files from nginx and what actually happens instead of telling: "it does not work". Most often it is not possible to give an answer if essential information is not included. However, in this case the answer is simple.

Answer (score 1):

Your location block is missing the `permanent` attribute. This should work:

```
location ~ ^/c/(?<section>[^/]+)/.+\.html$ {
    rewrite ^ http://www.domain.com/c/$section/ permanent;
}
```

I also removed the second capture group from regex since it is not needed. I also added the end of string identifier in the regex so that an URL like `http://www.domain.com/c/Integratori-di-Proteine/Universal-.html1234` would not cause a redirect but a 404 page.

Edit: Changed the capture so that it is captured into a named variable and also changed the regex pattern a bit.

Comment: I applied the rule but this http://www.bestintegratori.it/c/Integratori-di-Creatina/Swiss-Professional.html redirect to http://www.bestintegratori.it/c//

Comment: I changed it to use a variable, which should work now.